# File system fallback

Tags: linux, nfs

I'm using AWS' NFS in one of my EC2 instances. In the rare cases when it becomes unavailable I want to have a fallback. I thought of having two file systems in two different regions and then mounting them to the same mount point using [OverlayFS](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/overlayfs.html?highlight=overlayfs). Is that a workable solution? Is it a good idea or should I do something else?

Comment: "_Is that a workable solution?_" not really... you'll still have unavoidable calls to the NFS server for any modified content. OverlayFS isn't about redundancy so much as allowing modification to a read-only filesystem, or layering filesystems.

Comment: I thought if the call to the NFS fails it would go to the next one. I'm using them only for writes. Is there a different solution?

Comment: What do you use the NFS service for? Maybe the file system is not the best point to add redundancy.

Comment: If a call to the NFS server fails, then you'll get an error... and you are probably aware of how long it can take for an NFS error to come back. As @EugenRieck suggests, this isn't really the place to do what you're planning. Your question feels like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) - what exactly are you looking to achieve?

Comment: I'm using NFS to write temp files. When it goes down I don't want the writing to be disrupted too much. Changing the application is not the best option since it's very bad legacy code, so I prefer to do something on the system side.